# Java Compiled While loop is looking different

Tags: java, java-7

I am using java 7 update 26. I have a class where i have a while loop. When i decompiled that .class file with jd-gui (http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui) its giving me some strange while loop.

```
try {
  while (true) {
    c = in.read();
    if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || c == '-' || c == '+')
    {
      numBuf[len++] = (char) c;
    } else if (c == '.' || c == 'e' || c == 'E') {
      numBuf[len++] = (char) c;
      isFloat = true;
    } else if (c == -1) {
      throw new IOException("EOF");
    } else {
      in.unread(c);
    }
  }
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
  throw new IOException("Exception with Array ");
}
```

The compiled version is like the following:

```
try {
  while (true) {
    c = in.read();
    if (((c >= 48) && (c <= 57)) || (c == 45) || (c == 43))
    {
      numBuf[(len++)] = (char)c;
      continue; 
    } 
    if ((c != 46) && (c != 101) && (c != 69))
      break;
    numBuf[(len++)] = (char)c;
    isFloat = true;
  }
  if (c == -1) {
    throw new IOException("EOF");
  }
    in.unread(c);      
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException localArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) {
    throw new IOException("Exception with Array ");
}
```

My code seems totally different.. Any ideas?

Comment: Optimization, perhaps? Your character values are replaced with their numeric value, and your if-else is rearranged appropriately.

Comment: It has been optimized by compiler IMO.

Comment: As most have already pointed out, the characters have been converted into their respective ASCII values. What I'm not sure about is the change to your `if`/`else` statement. Is that really the decompiled version? It doesn't look correct, especially with the `in.unread(c);` now being shown outside of the `while` loop!?

Answer (score 3):

The 'X' is replaced with ASCII code for performance improvement.

And the if/else changed to continue/break to reduce the comparison, still for performance.

Answer (score 2):

This is the consequence of using a decompilator that used Java IL to produce source code.

The extra '()' and characters translated to digits has no impact on the code.

The change that remove the `else` block is also a optimization as it is not required.

```
  if (c == -1) {
      throw new IOException("EOF");
    } else {
      in.unread(c);
    }
```

is the same as

```
  if (c == -1) {
      throw new IOException("EOF");
   }

   in.unread(c);
```

Because the application will exit if the logic expresions is true.

BTW: You shouyld not used the `Exception` to control the logic of application. Instaed of `while(true)` use `while(c != -1)` then you do not need that last if

So the code look different but works in the same way.

TIP: 
If you want to diagnose your code, read the IL.

Answer (score 1):

The compiled version is using the ASCII values for characters,  if that is baffling you. There is no alarming change in the de-compiled code.

Comment: Should be a comment IMO.

Comment: @NarendraPathai Thats the only thing changed in the code, hence i put it as answer.

Comment: The else if ladder has also been optimized out.

Comment: HI, Thanks for your sugesstions, i am confused of the else if statements but not the ASCII chars. This is the one which scared me when i saw the compiled one.  if ((c != 46) && (c != 101) && (c != 69))
      break; I need to add to the StringBuilder if it matches that pattern. But, its breaking there out of while loop but not continuing.

Answer (score 1):

The code seems the same.
The decompiler just change your character into their ascii code : [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

The elsif has been replaced by a continue. 
It's the interpretation of the bytecode by the decompilater

Answer (score 0):

It has just changed characters to their respective ASCII values for better performance. 
you can refer to [ASCII table](http://www.ascii.cl/)